# Is there a C# method of hash generation where the order of the values doesn't matter?

Tags: c#, hash, compression

I'm looking to generate a hash from a list of values where something like:

54 2040 37 19 45

generates the same hash as

2040 45 19 54 37

or

dog cat house car

generates the same hash as:

house cat dog car

Basically where the values are all that matter, not the order

Comment: How about sorting the list before you hash it? Would that meet your needs?

Comment: Just use a commutative operator, like + or ^ (xor).  Always explain *why* you are asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution could be to sort the string alphabetically/numerically before calling the "ordinary" hash function like md5, sha-1, sha-256 and doing the same when de-hashing it.

Comment: And to sort, don't sort it.  In one pass increment the count for each byte in a table of 256 values.  Then you can again in one pass generate the sorted result.  O(n).

Comment: Mark can you elaborate what you mean? It seems interesting but I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 2):

Hash the elements individually and xor their hashes.

Beware, though, that I have no idea about any security implications of doing so (if that matters).